# StormCrawler's default-regex-filters.txt

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I have been messing with this for a while now, and have not been able to sort out how the default-regex-filters.txt file for StormCrawler works.

In one example I need to limit the crawler to ONLY crawl items under https://www.example.com/dev and none of the other directories on that site. I put the rule

```
+.*\/dev\/.*
```

into the last line of the default-regex-filters.txt but it doesn't seem to work. I thought standard regex-rules apply, but it doesn't seem to be the case. one of the examples above had / without the \ before it and it was working? I am rather confused by that, and wondering if there's a cheat sheet for the regex in that file so i can build these easier.

As a followup, is it also true that only one + filter can be in the file? I vaguely remember reading that, but wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many + filters in the files as you want.

The logic of the filtering is simply

```
 public String filter(URL pageUrl, Metadata sourceMetadata, String url) {
    for (RegexRule rule : rules) {
        if (rule.match(url)) {
            return rule.accept() ? url : null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

where *accept* indicates that the pattern has a +. If nothing matches the URL is filtered.

Could it be that you left

```
# accept anything else
+.
```

above the expression you added?

You might want to have a look at the [FastURLFilter](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/filtering/regex/FastURLFilter.java) which is a probably more intuitive.